# Error trying to create shortcut [C++]

Tags: c++, compilation, shortcut

I have these includes:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <winnls.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <shlobj.h> 
#include <shlguid.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

and I found this code to make shortcuts:

```
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc){ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)){ 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}
```

But I'm getting these compilation errors:
"no matching function for call to ‘IShellLinkA::SetPath(const WCHAR*&)’ candidate is: virtual HRESULT IShellLinkA::SetPath(const CHAR*)"

I get the same error for setDescription, apparently they are programmed as Virtual, which means there is no real code in them:

```
virtual HRESULT WINAPI SetPath(LPCSTR pszFile) = 0;
```

I must be missing a header file or something, but I have no clue. I'm a little bit lost, I think shouldn't be getting these errors. Any ideas?
Thankyou very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your project settings from `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` to `Use Unicode Character Set`.  This option is in the General configuration settings under Project Defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
psl->SetPath(CW2T(lpszPathObj));
```

if you have a MBCS project. In this case SetPath needs a char*.
This notation will always work even if you switch your project to Unicode.